# How do I go about solving this git conflict?

Tags: git

1. I have made a central bare shared repo at foo.org.
2. user A has done `git clone ssh://foo.org/blah.git`
3. user A has created file 'lol' which is a blank file. Commits it to local repo. Does `git push`
4. user B does `mkdir foo` and `cd foo`
5. user B then does `git clone ssh://foo.org/blah.git`.
6. user B edits `lol` file.
7. user A edits `lol` file.
8. user A commits and `git push` to central repo
9. user B commits and `git push` and is given:

   > error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://foo.org/blah.git'
   >   To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
   >   Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'non-fast forward'
10. user b does `git pull`

    > From ssh://foo.org/home/meder/central/foo
    >   08a0cda..fba6968  master     -> origin/master
    >   Auto-merging lol
    >   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lol
    >   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
11. user b does `vim lol` and edits file to his liking. then tries `git commit` afterwards and is given:

    > lol: needs merge
    >   lol: unmerged (039727ec5a50d0ed45ff67e6f4c9b953bd23c17d)
    >   lol: unmerged (9307e337aa159ed6574eb84532f107685e46a16c)
    >   lol: unmerged (f88ad411f67850938dc369426cdbba76812e9126)
    >   error: Error building trees

What do I have to do at this point? I tried a `git merge` but it says `fatal: You have not concluded your merge. (MERGE_HEAD exists)`

I know for sure I'm doing something stupidly wrong. Can someone just point out what it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Fix Merge Conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 11, has user b done a 'git add' to add their hand-merge, before 'git commit'?

Comment: hm, i actually think you're right. i didn't do an explicit `git add lol` on the hand-merge. so does git change the branch or un-add it? or did i never add it in the first place? *confused*

Comment: You have to 'git add' the modification before 'git commit'. 'git commit -a' will do the add for you, too. I know it's the same command as for adding a new file; you have to do the same for merges too.

Comment: A way to picture this is the think that you have to 'add' your modification/change to git.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be a comment. It's the answer!

Comment: @Graham: I think it's your phrasing of this as a question that got you that comment comment; requests for more information should be comments. You might want to edit it to be a statement (with an explanation). It is indeed the answer, though. (+1)

Comment: @meder: git does not change the branch or un-add content. It finds a conflict, and therefore does not know what content to add. It lets the user resolve the conflict (you mentioned editing the file), and then the user must tell git to add that *new* content. Yes, the content is new - git had no idea how you were going to resolve it. It would've resolved it for you if it did! So, you have to tell git: here, stage this content for commit. Same as with any other content you want git to know about.